# Add JButton array to a JPanel (buttons not visible)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I'm trying to create a simple calculator with Java. For that purpose I created an array of JButton and added them to the JPanel.

**The issue**: the buttons are not visible.

I also added a single JLabel and a single JButton for testing, and they show up correctly.

The code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("Test label", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JButton testButton = new JButton("Test button");

    JButton buttons[];

    Test() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();  

        for (int i = 0; i > 15; i++) {

            buttons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            panel.add(buttons[i], BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }

        panel.add(testButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(testLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test cTest = new Test();

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the default layout manager of a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout` , not `BorderLayout` .

Comment: Note2: if the layout manager of the panel was set to `BorderLayout`, you still would only see the last component since all are being added with `BorderLayout.CENTER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the condition in your for loop is invalid. Replace the **>** with **<**: The statement 0 > 15 is never is never evaluated to `true` which is why your loop never starts iterating:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
```

Also you must create the array with `new` keyword before you assign items to it. Otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`:

```
buttons = new JButton[15];
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I think that your for loop should like like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
```

And after that, in you have to initialize your buttons reference

```
JButton buttons[] = new JButton[15];
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you use a for loop you have to initialise your objects for every single loop.
If you have a TextView for example, you'll have to do:

```
TextHeaders[i] = new TextView([activity_name].this);
```

For your problem,

```
buttons[i] = new JButton (this);
```